Mode for editing helm templates (helm as in Helm Charts, not Emacs helm mode)
I am working with .yaml files that use Helm templates, with Helm not being related to the Emacs helm mode, but being the templating/package management frequently used when deploying Kubernetes packages.
These .yaml-with-template- files usually have an extension of .tpl and look like this:
{{ ...some code... }}
{{ ...some code... }}
normal:
   yaml:
     stuff: "hello"
     moreStuff: {{ ...more code... }}

Generally, the {{ ... }} constructs can be interspersed freely and are substituted by the Helm template engine, somewhat related to some templating package from the Go language.
I am aware how to activate yaml-mode for these files based on the file extension, but then yaml-mode just plain does not work at all. It gets confused at the first occurrence of {{, which is to be expected, anyway, as the template code is usually not syntactically correct YAML at all.
Is there some mode or collection of modes which can work with this? I seem to recall some kind of "super-mode" which was able to switch between other modes on a line by line basis - often useful when working with this style of text templates, but cannot for the life of me remember how it was called.
